# Countdown audio duration javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to countdown the duration of an audio file similar to iTunes and I can't get the formula quite right. I searched but can't find what I'm looking for.  I'm sure this will be some easy stackoverflow points for someone.

Here's a nearly working example of what I'm working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/philbot/tfSTh/

Basically, if you push play, it will start a timer for the song. Time elapsed works fine, however I'm having trouble with the countdown.  I can't get the seconds to countdown correctly. Here's the JS for the countdown portion: (please refer to my fiddle for the rest)

```
// Countdown
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    var timeleft = document.getElementById('timeleft');
    var ml = parseInt((audio.duration / 60 - audio.currentTime / 60) % 60);

    // Here's the incorrect seconds countdown calc
    var sl = parseInt(audio.duration % 60 - audio.currentTime);

    if (sl < 10) {
      timeleft.innerHTML = ml + ':0' + sl;
    }
    else {
      timeleft.innerHTML = '-' + ml + ':' + sl;
    }
}, false);
```

Thanks Everyone...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I simply just calculated the remaining time and formatted that, is that what you wanted?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tfSTh/1/

Comment: Of course! This works great. Should have thought of that, but I was stuck thinking about it the wrong way. I'll accept your answer as soon as time allows.

Comment: you are the hero @Esailija